# Mongo DB Update - Not Deleting the Empty fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

We are having Node Express API and the backend data store is Mongo DB. We use Mongoose package for interacting with the Mongo DB. The Mongoose Schema is as below:

```
const employeeSchema = new Schema<IEmployee, EmployeeModel>(
    {
        _id: { type: String, default: uuidv4() },
        providerIdentifier: { type: String, maxlength: 255 },
        firstName: { type: String, maxlength: 100 },
        lastName: { type: String, maxlength: 100 },
        hobbies: { type: String, maxlength: 1000 },
        employeeId: { type: String, maxLength: 4, immutable: true },
        department: { type: String, maxlength: 100 },
        phoneNumbers: [phoneNumberSchema],
        emails: [emailSchema],      
    }
);

const emailSchema = new Schema<IEmail>(
    {
        emailAddress: { type: String, trim: true, maxlength: 255 },
        emailType: { type: String, trim: true },
    },
    { _id: false },
);

const phoneNumberSchema = new Schema<IPhoneNumbers>(
    {
        phoneNumber: { type: String, trim: true, maxlength: 50 },
        phoneType: { type: String, trim: true },
    },
    { _id: false },
);
```

In the mongo db for the employee document, we do have an extra field - `isExecutive`. This field is derived through a Mongo Trigger and is not exposed in the API and hence we are not maintaining it in the Mongoose Schema.

For updating a document, we are using `findByIdAndUpdate` command and pass the `employee` object obtained from the API request. We are facing an issue when trying to update. If an employee has `hobbies` data populated while creating the document in Mongo collection, if the `hobbies` field is not sent in the API, it should actually delete the field from the Mongo Document, but it is getting protected and is not removed. Same is the case with `email` and `phone` collections. If we do not send these collections, the data in the Mongo Data store is being protected. We could see that the `findOneAndReplace` is an option which will replace all the contents of the document. But, in that case, we will loose the `isExecutive` flag which is calculated internally and not exposed in the API.

Is there any way we can achieve this?

Comment: Maybe try `hobbies: null`

Comment: but this field is an optional field and the user who calls the API can actually not send this information

Comment: It is not clear to me if you want to delete it or not

Comment: You can always use a regular update and control the exact fields that you are updating.

Comment: if the hobbies is not passed in the inbound API request, it should get deleted from the datastore. But that is not happening. If we use regular update also, it does not work

Comment: If you use a regular update you can defiantly `$set` it to null. If you are using `findByIdAndUpdate` you can probability do it as well.

Comment: With a regular update, you can set to null or use unset if you want. See [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9Mq5e5oS70G). `findByIdAndUpdate` should be similar